# При инициализации 2D - массива первая строка инициализируется мусором

Tags: c++, массивы

Решаю задачу нахождения LSC "Наибольшей общей последовательности". Мне необходимо построить двумерный массив [длина строки 1] [длина строки 2] и заполнить его нулями. при попытке так сделать первая строка массива заполняется мусором. предполагаю, что это связано с тем, что длина строки не является constexpr, но подтверждений этому найти не смог.

```
int main() {
    string a = "asdfga";
    string b = "qwerty";
    auto x = a.size() + 1;
    auto y = b.size() + 1;
  
    int arr[x][y] = {0};
    for (auto i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        for(auto j = 0; j < y; ++j) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

По совету [HolyBlackCat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/215103/holyblackcat)  попробовал реализовать с одним вектором. Вроде работает, но пока не понял почему вектор составляется по столбцам, а не построчно

```
string a; //"baccbca"
string b; //"abcabaac"
cin >> a >> b; 
size_t x = a.size() + 1;
size_t y = b.size() + 1;
cout << x + 1 << " " << y + 1 << endl;

vector<int> arr((x)*(y), 0);
for (int i = 1; i < x; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j < y; ++j) {
        if (a[i - 1] == b[j - 1])
            arr[j + i * y] = arr[(j + i * y) - y - 1] + 1;
        else
            arr[j + i * y] = max(arr[(j + i * y) - y], arr[(j + i * y) - 1]);
    }
}
cout << arr[x*y - 1];
```

Comment: LCS (longest common subsequence) - задача нахождения наибольшей (самой длинной) общей последовательности. Необходимо построить двумерный массив [длина 1-й строки + 1] [длина 2-й строки + 1] и заполнить его нулями. При попытке вывести результат, первая строка двумерного массива заполняется мусором, остальные 0. Предполагаю, что дело в том, что длины строк не являются constexpr, но найти этому подтверждения не могу

Comment: Я впервые задаю вопрос по программированию здесь. В чем проблема? почему должны закрыть вопрос? Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Понятно! спасибо, отредактировал

Comment: Стандарт С++ требует, чтобы размер массива был известен во время компиляции. Если ваш компилятор такое пропускает, то настройки стоят недостаточно строгие. То, что вы видите, это в каком-то смысле баг ГЦЦ, который происходит при попытке инициализировать массив, размер которого во время компиляции незвестен.

Comment: Ну т.е. объяснения этому "багу" нет, почему именно первая строка заполняется мусором начиная со второго элемента, а с остальными все в порядке?

Comment: @Ermakov -  вам написали объяснение. Вы написали код, который отклоняется от принятого стандарта языка. Не все ошибки в программе ловятся в процессе синтаксического анализа - программа может быть формально правильной, но содержать в себе UB - неопределенное поведение. UB - это особенность в частности C++ - если вы написали программу с отступлением от стандарта языка, она может работать произвользным образом (в том числе и так как вы задумали).

UB в программах на С++ категорически не допустимо.

Comment: Про UB и стандарт понятно, про то как решить проблему и построить двумерный массив пока непонятно, возможно правильным решением будет использовать vector или deque, буду гуглить дальше. спасибо

Comment: Да, правильно взять `vector`. Причем желательно одномерный. Еще вариант заполнять массив нулями не при инициализации, а отдельно, но это не по фен-шую. Если вы убираете нестандартный массив переменной длины, советую покрутить настройки компилятора, чтобы в следующий раз он выдал вам ошибку.

Comment: проще всего делать так:: если известны размеры n*m, то `vector<vector <int>> dpdp; dp.resize(n); for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) dpdp.assign(m,0);`

Comment: @Neuro - у этого способа есть недостаток, он недружелюбен к кэшированию, так как строки полученной матрицы будут лежать в памяти как попало, а не подряд.

Comment: Это скорее про олпрогу, поэтому тут так можно, но по хорошему ему надо просто int[][], так как другое там не нужно

Comment: Ну или в крайнем случае при создании есть перегруз со встроенным assign

Comment: `int arr[x][y] ={0};` - инициализирует только первый элемент нулём. `int arr[x][y] ={};` - весь массив конструктором `int` (*тоже нулями*). Почему только один элемент становиться нулём, это надо покопаться в стандарте.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Нет, `{0}` тоже все заполняет нулями. В общем случае, если в фигурных скобках меньше элементов, чем в массиве/стрктуре, остальные зануляются. Это GCC багает на массивах переменной длины...

Answer (score 0):

В общем задача наибольшей общей подпоследовательности решается с помощью ДП, строим двумерный вектор

```
vector <vector <int>> dp;
int n = a.size();
int m = b.size();
dp.resize(max(n,m));
for (size_t i = 0; i < max(n,m); ++i) dp[i].assign(min(m,n),0);
```

Дальше мы работаем через рекурсивную формулу:
**lcs(i,j)** ==

1. **lcs(i-1,j-1)+1**  {x[i]==y[i]}
2. **lcs(max(lcs(i-1,j),lcs(i,j-1))** else

Comment: А что такое ДП?

Comment: Динамическое программирование, вопрос как вы собрались решать данную задачу без него?

Comment: Я не профессиональный программист, профильного образования не имею. Обучаюсь самостоятельно, в сокращениях и аббревиатурах в части касающейся не силен) а решал я с помощью youtube, google и МТ.